# Using RabbitMQ in a webapplication, can multiple threads work on the same queue

Tags: grails, queue, rabbitmq, messaging

I have a web-application where users upload files that are processed by the web-applicaiton. The first thing I do is put the request in a RabbitMQ queue. These requests are then processed in a queued manner in the background one-by-one. All of this works fine.

From my analysis, I've noticed that the problem arises when one of the requests in the queue takes a long time to process. When this happens, the requests behind the long running requests get delayed as well.

**Example**

```
User 1 uploads DOC file   at 12:32:10*
User 2 uploads DOCX file  at 12:32:11*
User 3 uploads PDF file   at 12:32:12*
User 1 uploads PPT file   at 12:32:13*
```

`* -` the date time stamp in the DB that reflects then request was created

At this point the queue would look like this and in this order:

```
DOC, DOCX, PDF, PPT
```

I know `PDF` files take longer to process but `PPT` does not take long. Since `PDF` is processed before `PPT`, `PPT` takes a long time to finish as well.

After all requests are processed, the time stamps in the DB look like this:

```
User 1 uploads DOC file   at 12:32:10*     12:32:11**
User 2 uploads DOCX file  at 12:32:11*     12:32:12**
User 3 uploads PDF file   at 12:32:12*     12:32:20**
User 1 uploads PPT file   at 12:32:13*     12:32:40**
```

`** -` the date time stamp in the DB that reflects then request was finished

Notice that PPT takes `27` seconds to complete only because it is behind a `PDF`. In my testing if it is before `PDF` then it only takes `2 to 3` seconds

PS: I'm using the RabbitMQ plugin in a grails application

**Question**

Is there a way to have multiple threads process the requests in a queue in a web-application? I'm thinking that if multiple threads are working on the queue then even if one request (PDF in the example above) takes longer to process others can still finish (PPT in the example above)?  If so, how can I enforce multiple threads to work on the queue?

Is there a better architecture I should be utilizing such that the requests get processed sooner rather than waiting on request that takes long time to process?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want that during single web-request multiple threads start consuming messages from the same queue in parallel? If so, Then just do it. It's ok, but pay attention to client library implementation to use it correctly in multithreaded env. If you are worrying about long messages processing by some consumer, it's ok. Stalled messages will not stop messages consuming by other consumers.

Comment: @zaq178miami yeah, I want multiple threads to work on the queue so that long running tasks don't delay processing of the tasks behind it. I've updated my question with a detailed example

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is to have more than one consumer in attached to your queue. So while one consumer processes the PDF, then another can process the next file.

In your case you probably want to have a low value for `basic_qos` as well. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

This pattern is know as `competing consumers` here: http://www.eaipatterns.com/CompetingConsumers.html

Comment: hmmm I'm confused by `more than one consumer`. The code that processes the PDF (and PPT) is part of my web-application. Does that mean I need to port these pieces of code out and turn them into a different application/service?

Comment: FWIW, I'm using this plugin to work with RabbitMQ http://grails.org/plugin/rabbitmq

Comment: I'm not used to grails, but in RabbitMQ you usually have your consumers running in the background separate from your webapp. Then you can run many instances of them

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that beat the purpose of using a queue? We have a similar application which uses RabbitMQ. What we do is to have different queues for each type. So if its pdf, we have a pdf queue, a ppt queue, a doc queue and a docx queue.

We use Java and Octobot as the client for connecting to the MQ. So we can use the same jar, with a yml file listing all the queues. The JSON has the task name. Its the same in each json message that is sent into the queue. So the same class works in all cases.

Also regd the competing consumers... I think we do that too.. We have multiple server instances running octobot(Java). So these are registered as consumers on RabbitMQ server. 
So RabbitMQ decides which one is free based on the last ack received and sends the message accordingly.

Hope this helps.